Vue2 and Vue3 on the same web page
For a very niche and specific reason I need both major versions of VueJS (2 & 3) to run concurrently on the same web page and each run their own plugins independently of each other. This will all need to run through Vite and have strong Typescript support.
This type of requirement isn't new to me so I pretty much have both instances of Vue 2 & 3 running independently on the same web page, however when trying to run Vuetify in combination I get the following error:

Which only happens on the following line
async start() {
  // Libraries
  await injectLibraries()
  // Theme
  Vue.use(Vuetify) // Multiple instance error generated here (Vue and Vuetify are V2 and on the window global)

  // Validate
  const el = document.querySelector('#v2')
  if (!el) {
    return
  }

  // Vue/vuetify setup
  // Without the  Vue.use(Vuetify) line this continues with zero errors
  // But then Vuetify and all components don't work
  const vuetify = new (window as any).Vuetify({
    // theme: { disable: true }
  })
  this.vue = new Vue({
    el: el,
    vuetify,
    mounted: () => {
      this.onMounted()
    }
  } as any)
}

For reference V3 is created in the "normal" way:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
// This does not need Vue.use(Vuetify)
createApp(App).use(router).use(vuetify).mount('#app')

My best guess is that each library tries to create a $attrs and $listener object to bind to, and because V3 gets to it first, V2 complains.
My next step is to create a custom build of Vue2/Vuetify2 to change any core bindings, but before that I wanted to see if anyone had any less drastic ideas on how to do this.

Project setup:

Vue3 & Vuetify3 are installed via npm
Vue2 is a compiled esm.js bundle which is directly injected into the page
Vuetify2 is a compiled .js bundle which is directly injected into the page

Vue3 gets created in main.ts which is the entrypoint of the app, after the page has mounted and the system is working then I inject the Vue2 libs. After checking Vue2 adds Vue to the window scope, but due to bundling Vue3 directly this has no impact as Vue3 does not add Vue to window.

Please, provide a way to reproduce. It's unknown how the apps are related. It matters how they are loaded and bundled, this was omitted. The error is caused by Vuetify 2 https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.7.2/packages/vuetify/src/install.ts#L9 . Please, add the error as text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Might be a good idea to check the given error Github issue or add a comment to it since it's stated in the error IMO.

Im not trying to be mysterious here it just took a lot to get it to this point, perhaps this question is a bit too broad for SO.  The error response leads back to the issue of trying to load two Vu2 instances, but this usecase is a bit different from that as I can't simply extend two instances anymore. @kissu

Turns out I was accidentally importing Vue from the index page as well as from a script injection. Will close this question when I can.
